# AIDL generated file compile errors with SDK tools Version 21

Tags: android, aidl

I upgraded the Android SDK tools to version 21 (and subsequently 21.0.1) and now all files generated from my aidl files contain compile errors related to incorrect @Override keyword being inserted into some of the generated functions. e.g

```
@Override
public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return this;
}
```

I will post my workaround in an answer,
Aidan

Comment: As a workaround I copied the aidl binary from platform_tools in sdk 20.0.1 and overwrote the aidl binary in version 21. All generated files are now compiling and problem seems to be solved. Just updated to 21.0.1 but the Aidl problem is still present until copying over old binary. Hope this helps, Aidan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your real problem, most likely, is that your project (or workspace) in Eclipse is not set up to validate Java code against Java 1.6. `@Override` of methods implemented for an interface was not supported in Java 1.5 and is supported in Java 1.6. Modify your project (or workspace) properties such that the Java validation is for 1.6, and the generated `@Override` annotations should be fine.

Comment: This answer saved me so much trouble today you have no idea, I met a deadline rather than failed to do so thanks to this... thank you!

Comment: Thanks, the issue was a new open source project was imported that was using 1.5 as opposed to the workspace-wide configured 1.6.

Comment: Thanks, I use 1.7 but error happens... I would never think that newer version won't support something that older supports.

Comment: @timyau: While you may have Java 1.7 installed, that has nothing to do with what rules Eclipse will use for validating Java syntax.